# Why am I getting a "Circular View Path Error"?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I am getting a "Circular View Path Error" but I don't know why. If I am understanding it correctly this error occurs when you are stuck in a infinite loop. But I don't see an infinite Loop in my code. I googled the error, and tested every solution I found, but nothing worked.

MyUserDetails:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.isActive();
        this.authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(active);
        System.out.println(authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

User:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lehrer", schema = "public")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String roles;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Rest Controller/ HomeResource:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeResource {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return ("<h1>Hier wird der Vertretungsplan einsehbar sein</h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/lehrer")
    public String lehrer(){
        return ("<h1>Hier wird das Formular einsehbar sein</h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return ("<h1>Hier wird die Admin Übersicht einsehbar sein</h1>");
    }

}
```

MyUserDetailsService:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan;

import de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails;
import de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUserName(userName);

       user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + userName + " not found!"));

       return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
    }

}
```

User Repository:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan;

import de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Security Configuration:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/lehrer").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","LEHRER")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

And finally, this is my main:

```
package de.gabriel.vertretungsplan;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class VertretungsplanApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VertretungsplanApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I don't think, the errors origin can be in the database, but if it is, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99GOw.png) is the contents of the "lehrer" table in the database "vertretungsplan":

Here is the error log:

```
2022-04-17 00:50:57.562 ERROR 14740 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:237) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Here are the debug logs(they are too long, so I posted the longs of when the error happend):

```
2022-04-17 00:58:48.395 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
2022-04-17 00:58:48.395 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_,
        user0_.active as active2_0_,
        user0_.password as password3_0_,
        user0_.roles as roles4_0_,
        user0_.user_name as user_nam5_0_ 
    from
        public.lehrer user0_ 
    where
        user0_.user_name=?
admin
$2a$12$E8STVE26N/QpoL90VfoOAuFRnYvbfzHKlbGRe.KVOMYCqKtDKNK2G
true
[ADMIN]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.796 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2022-04-17 00:58:48.797 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9
2022-04-17 00:58:48.797 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy  : Replaced CSRF Token
2022-04-17 00:58:48.798 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails@69c46690, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.798 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/admin
2022-04-17 00:58:48.798 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails@69c46690, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@35a28abb]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.798 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails@69c46690, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@35a28abb]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.798 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-04-17 00:58:48.801  INFO 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/admin':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@328dbcd1

servletPath:/admin
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
referer: http://localhost:8080/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: Webstorm-bca5ba46=692b9f6e-b03a-4cb4-8435-ea3fef371fc4; JSESSIONID=A90C1A49C3CF4D7943EE0ABBD989B1D4


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2022-04-17 00:58:48.802 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /admin
2022-04-17 00:58:48.802 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails@69c46690, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.802 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=de.gabriel.vertretungsplan.models.MyUserDetails@69c46690, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=CD2D5F40C901F8A7CF32826E28A596C9], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.802 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8080/admin
2022-04-17 00:58:48.803 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /admin] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
2022-04-17 00:58:48.803 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2022-04-17 00:58:48.803 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-04-17 00:58:48.805  INFO 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1f38c9b6

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
referer: http://localhost:8080/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: Webstorm-bca5ba46=692b9f6e-b03a-4cb4-8435-ea3fef371fc4; JSESSIONID=A90C1A49C3CF4D7943EE0ABBD989B1D4


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: where is the error? where are your spring security debug logs?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am so sorry, it's just late, and I am sitting on this for 4 hours now. I just added the error and I don't have any debug logs because I currently don't use them.

Comment: then please lerarn how to use them, how to enable them before you ask on stack overflow.

Comment: do you have spring mvc on your classpath?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Sorry, I can't post the complete debugging logs because I am getting this error on Stackoverflow(
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 95589.), but I am going to try to paste everything from the debugging logs in there, because a lot are duplicates

Comment: Sorry, @Toerktumlare, I don't fully understand your question about MVC. What do you mean by "on my classpath"? ^^ After my understanding this is using the MVC Pattern because there is a view and I can change the view over my Controller(/RestController). And the view is changing(or should change) from login to whatever the RestController returns, which is based on the URL. But I am new to Spring Security and Spring in general, so you can tell me if I am wrong. But I still think, I should have the right to ask a question here, even if I am not a pro at Spring Security

Comment: what is expected before you ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users if you dont understand what im asking, then you should google and read up on what classpath is and means. The log you posted does not contain the error message. You must understand that its very hard for us to solve problems unless we have the full picture, full logs, or a running example. Your logs you posted does not contain the error message so its basically impossible for us to follow the code execution. Good luck with your problem

Comment: stack overflow is a last resort, you ask here when you have googled everything, learnt everything about your problem, debugged your problem, read the logs, followed the code, read all about all the errors. When you havnt found an answer after a week, you ask here. Because then you are asking someone that has done all that, someone that has read everything, spent all their time on solving problems for FREE, to just give you an answer? asking on stack overflow taking up someones time shouldn't be taken lightly, its a Q&A site, not a forum. You can ask, but no one owes you an answer remember that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error, because you did not fully configure Spring MVC, namely error handling part (and probably others).

Chain of events is as follows:

1. Call API and get 403 forbidden resource
   `2022-04-17 00:58:48.803 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /admin] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')] 2022-04-17 00:58:48.803 DEBUG 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code`
2. Spring redirects to `/error` view:
   `Request received for GET '/error': org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1f38c9b6 servletPath:/error`
3. Here something happens (it was not found, or something is missing), it leads to another error -> and here is when exception happens:
   `javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)`

Solution:

1. Try to search by "springboot mvc set up white lable error page".
2. And also check why you get 403 status in the first place, as according to logs, you logged in as admin user. Please, read about spring security adding `ROLE_` prefix. Most probably, in the DB it has to be `ROLE_ADMIN` and in the code `hasRole('ADMIN')`

Hope, it helped

Comment: Thanks so much! It was because I didn't had the ROLE_ Prefix. I even had it in my other database, I don't know why I forgot about that here, but yeah, I also was wondering why I got a 403, I thought that I would have to get a 500 Internal Server Error, but everything is fixed now. And thanks for analizing the Debug/Error log and telling me exactly, what happend! ^^

Comment: I am glad I could help :) But even though the error is gone now, there is still an issue with the exception-handling scenario. If you would get any other exception, or try to access admin-resource with some other user (where it really should be 403 forbidden), you would still get this issue with `circular view path /error`.

Comment: Yeah, right. And after my understanding this is happening because it tries to redirect, but because it can't redirect to an error page it just gets stuck in a loop and drops this error, right? So I just would have to make an error page or would it also be possible to throw an exception?

Comment: In essence, yes - you understood correctly. But how to handle errors - it is a big topic, it is better to read some article about it or tutorial - so that you understand what is the better way for you.

Comment: Okay, then I am going to read more about it. Because before I only did GUI and Consoleapplications and there I would do try and catch or throw an exception. But if it's a big topic, I am ofc going to inform myself about it. Thanks for the advice! ^^